# Setting timezone while using jQuery CountDown

Tags: jquery, jquery-countdown

Currently we have this code, which works, except it needs to use a specified timezone, rather than the user's timezone:

```
 $('#countdown').countdown('<?php echo $date_end?>').on('update.countdown', function(event) {
            var format = '%-S second%!S';

            if (event.offset.years > 0 || event.offset.weeks > 0 || event.offset.days > 0 || event.offset.hours > 0 || event.offset.minutes > 0) {

                if(event.offset.minutes > 0) {
                    format = '%-M minute%!M ' + format;
                }
                if(event.offset.hours > 0) {
                    format = '%-H hour%!H ' + format;
                }
                if(event.offset.days > 0) {
                    format = '%-d day%!d ' + format;
                }
                if(event.offset.weeks > 0) {
                    format = '%-w week%!w ' + format;
                }
            }
           $(this).html(event.strftime(format));
        }).on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
           $(this).html('Finished');
        });
```

I have seen several examples of adding timezones, but none are using the jquery countdown plugin in the same way we are.

Any ideas on how to add +10 as the current timezone? so it uses that rather than the user's timezone?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding the way you are using the plugin, or if it's even the same plugin as this: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html#zones However, I used the plugin on a site and passed it the date/time to countdown to in timezone -7 like this: jQuery('#countdown').countdown({until: new Date(2020, 1-1, 11, 5, 35, 35), timezone:-7, format:'YODHMS', compact: true}); 

Perhaps this helps?

Answer (score 5):

I am guessing you are using https://github.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown, because it doesn't have timezone options to use it.

I used moment.js and moment-timezone-with-data.js(contains all the timezones) to handle timezone.

```
<div data-countdown="2015/05/20"  data-zone="US/Central" class="countdown"></div>
```

function to convert the date to proper timezone and returns in milliseconds

```
var timefun = function (countdown,zone){
 var date = moment.tz(countdown,"YYYY/MM/DD",zone);
 return date.valueOf();   
}
```

make use of the above function to pass milliseconds as an argument to jQuery.countdown()

```
$(".countdown").countdown(timefun($(".countdown").data("countdown"),$(".countdown").data("zone")))
```

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/heLrsnqx/2/

if you are using http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html, refer following example

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/w1oyv8kv/

Comment: Hi. I am using this plugin: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html - calling it as per the example code in the question above

Comment: Thanks the keithwood example works well, EXCEPT, it is adding an erroneous 3 in-front of the days, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/w1oyv8kv/3/

Comment: month ranges from 0 to 11, you mentioned 2015,5,30 it falls under June , if you are looking for May change it to 2015,4,30

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the actual date that is used in the code is coming from that PHP snippet. You can set the default timezone in PHP using:

```
date_default_timezone_set($timezone_identifier);
```

`$timezone_identifier` is a string that can be things like `'UTC'` or `'America/Los_Angeles'`.

For a full list of supported timezone identifiers, see the [related PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Comment: Correct, it is being parsed in by PHP. In this format: 2015-05-14 17:30:00
Using php or javascript, how can i tell javascript though that this date/time is in GMT+10 rather than the users own timezone?

Comment: I think what Michal is saying is that you can set up an array like this: `var timeZones = [ "GMT", "EST", "CMT" ];` and then do something like `date_default_timezone_set( timeZones[1] );`

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, you can access the finalDate object with `event.finalDate`. So if you can't set the timezone server side, do `event.finalDate.setUTCHours(10)` before calling `event.strftime`

More on setUTCHours here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCHours

Comment: I have tried adding event.finalDate.setUTCHours(10); just before $(this).html(event.strftime(format)); and nothing changes.